# how to upload multiple images to a form with fields and two buttons to upload images?

Tags: python, django

I have a form divided into 3 tabs, in tab 2 and in tab 3 you have to upload multiple images respectively. The information that I have found about it, for the most part I do not understand and the one that I have seen easily, throws me this error:

```
TypeError: Carro() got an unexpected keyword argument 'images'
```

can you help me tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

> models.py

```
class Carro(models.Model):
    placas=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    marca=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cliente= models.ForeignKey(Clientes, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    fotosCarro=models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to="images/")
    garantia=models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to="images/")
    fecha_registros = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.placas} {self.marca}{self.cliente}{self.fotosCarro}{self.garantia}' \
               f'{self.fecha_registros}'
```

> forms.py

```
class CarroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Carro
        fields = ['placas','marca','cliente','fotosCarro','garantia']
        exclude = ['fecha_registros']
        widgets = {
            'placas': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={

                    'class': 'form-control',

                }
            ),
            
            'marca': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={

                    'class': 'form-control'
                }
            ),
            
            'cliente': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-select'
                }
            ),
            'fotosCarro':forms.FileInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'type-file',
                    'multiple': True,
                    'id': 'file-input',
                    'onchange':'preview()',
                }
            ),
            'garantia':forms.FileInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'type-file',
                    'multiple': True,
                    'id': 'file-inputz',
                    'onchange': 'previewz()',
                    # 'id':'pro-images',
                    # 'click': "$('#pro-images').click()",
                }
            ),
            'fecha_registros': forms.DateInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),

        }
```

> views.py

```
def create_carros(request):
    form = CarroForm(request.POST or request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CarroForm(request.POST or request.FILES)
        images = request.FILES.getlist('fotosCarro')
        garantias = request.FILES.getlist('garantia')
        for image in images:
            Carro.objects.create(images=image)
        for garantia in garantias:
            Carro.objects.create(garantias=garantia)


    images = Carro.objects.all()
    garantias = Carro.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'carros/carros-form-add.html', {'images': images,'garantias': garantias,'form':form})
```

Comment: Please give the full error message and show which line causes the error.

Comment: I just did what was suggested in the comment below and now I get this error django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "tipo" of relation "cars_car" violates not-null constraint

Comment: After you have read more about forms and tried some more things along those lines, you should post a new question. It is impossible for us to solve your new error without the current version of your code after you made changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Carro.objects.create(images=image)
```

to

```
Carro.objects.create(fotosCarro=image)
```

The keyword argument must match a field that you defined in the `Carro` class.

Note that this will fix the immediate error, but probably still won't do what you want. Also, you are doing WAY too much here. I suggest you read more about forms. If you use forms correctly, you can reduce your view code to this:

```
def create_carros(request):
    form = CarroForm(request.POST or request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

You will also need to add error handling when the form is invalid and render the form with error messages.

Comment: yes in fact It changes the error for another one, I don't understand why the view doesn't do what I want. Is it my view problem? Can you give me some clue to investigate? I'm stuck

Comment: As I said in my answer, I suggest you read more about forms and validation. You might need to read about how to use forms in views as well. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/) is a great place to start and has a good example.